# ¿Por qué la función lambda difiere de la función parcial?

Tags: python, python-2.7, funciones

Me he topado con una sorpresa al tratar de cambiar algunas funciones [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) por funciones parciales usando [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), el tema parece estar relacionado con las variables aunque ambas funciones se encuentran en el mismo "scope".

He creado este ejemplo sencillo para que puedan entender el problema:

```
>>> import functools
>>> multiplicar = lambda x, y: x * y
>>> variable = 5
>>> multiplicador_1 = lambda y: multiplicar(variable, y)
>>> multiplicador_2 = functools.partial(multiplicar, variable)
>>> print multiplicador_1(4), multiplicador_2(4)
20 20
```

Ambas funcionan perfecto y retornan el mismo resultado. Pero observen lo que pasa si cambiamos el valor de `variable`:

```
>>> variable = 10
>>> print multiplicador_1(4), multiplicador_2(4)
40 20
```

Los resultados difieren como si `multiplicador_2` no estuviera respetando el valor actual de `variable` en el "scope". ¿Qué está pasando?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esto sucede porque **en Python las clausuras y las *lambdas* utilizan *late binding***, "un mecanismo según el cual el método o la función llamados son resueltos en tiempo de ejecución" ([*late binding* en Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding)). En cambio, la función que has creado usando `functools.partial` es un ejemplo de *early binding*, y por tanto está tomando el valor de la variable que le asignaste al principio.

- En [este artículo en inglés de Saúl Ibarra](http://code.saghul.net/index.php/2010/11/20/lambda-vs-functools-partial/) se analiza el problema.
- En [esta sección de la *Python Guide*](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) se detallan otros problemas parecidos que pueden aparecer.
- En [este email de python-dev](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-April/044555.html) Guido van Rossum justifica la elección de *late binding* en el contexto de la PEP 289 que se aprobó para Python 2.4.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces, ¿esto está relacionado con los "Closures" en Python?

Comment: En realidad, las lambdas funcionan igual. Creo que es más claro si edito la respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto, ¡se entiende!